# where am I going wrong with solving this equation?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics

solve $z^2=2e^{5{\pi}i/6}$.

Well, clearly $z={\sqrt{2}}e^{5{\pi}i/12}$ is a root so its' conjugate $z={\sqrt{2}}e^{-5{\pi}i/12}$ is the other root.

But I can also argue $z=-{\sqrt{2}}e^{5{\pi}i/12}$ is a root which when simplified is $z={\sqrt{2}}e^{-7{\pi}i/12}$

which is a distinct root from the other two. But a quadratic has only 2 roots.

Thanks

Comment: It is not the conjugate, and is not a root. By the way, is there an $i$ missing?

Comment: "Its conjugate is the other root": are you sure ? Does $(z^*)^{2}=z^2$ hold ?

Comment: @AndréNicolas there is an $i$ missing in the obvious place. Sorry. Does the conjugate pairs thing only hold when coefficients are real-hence not in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an algebraic equation like
$$az^2+bz+c=0.$$
Taking the conjugate, it becomes
$$a^*(z^*)^2+b^*z^*+c^*=0.$$
If the coefficients are real, this is the same as
$$a(z^*)^2+bz^*+c=0,$$
showing that if $z$ is a root, so is $z^*$.

The property does not hold for complex coefficients, as you get two different equations.

Answer (score 2):

The conjugate of this root is not another root. Note that in general 
$$\begin{align}
&(a+bi)^2=(a-bi)^2
\\\iff& a^2+2abi-b^2=a^2-2abi-b^2
\\\iff&2abi=-2abi
\\\iff& a=0\,\,\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,\,\, b=0
\end{align}$$

Hence $(z)^2=(\bar{z})^2$ if and only if $z$ is pure real or pure imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

$$z={\sqrt{2}}e^{-5{\pi}/12}\\
z^2=2e^{-5\pi/6}\ne2e^{5\pi/6}$$